# how to play live streamings?

Tags: html, flash

i wanna play .asx and .swf formats.

can you help me how to play these formats in website. below are the streamings i want to play

http://www.radiokhushi.com/asx/liveaus1.asx

http://www.radiokhushi.com/liveaus.swf

Thanks,
Srikanth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a a bit long [article](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/video.html) but it contains everything you want to embed a video to your web site.

Comment: thank you............will that flow player play .asx format and .swf format live streamings?

Comment: I've never used that. But the article says yes. Better to have a quick try :)